# Showing update time like Twitter's update notification

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentJs for finding difference from now to a specific date as below:

```
moment([MyDate]).fromNow();
```

The code gives me results as below:

> "a few minutes ago" or "10 hours ago" ...

I tried to change that as below to find difference as seconds

```
moment([MyDate]).fromNow().asSeconds();
```

but the code doesn't work.

So I would like to implement codes like Twitter's last update notification. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want the output to be. What did you expect `moment([MyDate]).fromNow().asSeconds();` return? Maybe if you described what "Twitter's update notification" looks like for people who don't know.

Comment: I thought, if I can get result as seconds I can show "6 mins ago" or "30 sec ago" or showing with whatever I want string in different language with using if conditition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the diff between 2 dates in seconds : `moment().diff(mydate, 'seconds')`